# How to change python dataframe's content?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df:

```
                  Open    Volume  Adj Close     Ticker  
Date                                                                   
2006-11-22  140.750000   45505300   114.480649   SPY 
2006-11-22  100.470001     274000   72.382071    AGG
```

I want to change df to another dataframe Open price like below:

```
                  SPY    AGG  
Date                                                                   
2006-11-22  140.750000  100.470001
```

It only use open's data and two tickers, so how to change one dataframe to another?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.reset_index().pivot(index='Date', columns='Ticker', values='Open')
print (df)
Ticker             AGG     SPY
Date                          
2006-11-22  100.470001  140.75
```

Or [`pandas.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot.html):

```
df = pd.pivot(index=df.index, columns=df.Ticker, values=df.Open)
print (df)
Ticker             AGG     SPY
Date                          
2006-11-22  100.470001  140.75
```